# Nhibernate - Mapping information

Tags: orm, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using Fluent NHibernate in a simple project and I would be able to get some informations about identifier property name, foreign key property name and version property name.

Nowdays, I know just one way to retrieve the identifier property name:

```
string primaryKeyName = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession().SessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(typeof(MyClass).Name).IdentifierPropertyName;
```

Is There some way to get foreign and version proprety name too?

Answer (score -1):

Don't really know what you mean but the meta data object has all the information about the mapping of your object

Internal version if you meant this?

```
var postMeta = sessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(typeof(Post)); 
var version = postMeta.VersionProperty;
```

Then there are some collections which store the types, nullability, names and laziness of all the properties of your entity

```
var lazzyProperties = meta.PropertyLaziness;
var propertyNames = meta.PropertyNames;
//etc...
```

the PropertyTypes array actually stores a Bag object if there is a Bag mapping etc... Somewhere in those objects you'll find some properties where nHibernate internally stores the foreign key relationships, from<->to etc...

Hope this helps

Comment: PropertyLaziness return an array of bool and it cannot help me. PropertyTypes don't give me any information about foreign key names and name of property versione (I mean as timestamp property). Can you give me some more example?

Comment: @bit no, sorry. Simply debug through it yourself, set watch on the objects and check out the information you'll get... and/or look into the code of nHibernate...